# Fetch as Google returns 404 error for Angular 6 Routed URLs

Tags: angular

While checking "Fetch as Google" for Angular Routed Links "http://www.example.com/**contact**". It is returned as Not Found error. Sitemap as those links, but they are not indexed except the index page. What should I do?

Comment: You'll need to use Angular Universal to be able to return a completely rendered, spider-able URL. Search engine spiders typically don't work with dynamically rendered content.

Comment: I guess Angular Universal is buit in with Angular. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a separate set of modules to enable server-side rendering: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: @Brandon, Thanks. I will check that link.

Comment: You're welcome. Universal has worked very well for me on a number of projects.